# Datepicker month/year not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a date picker that's working in Chrome but the month and year dropdown don't work in firefox. Why would this happen?

**jQuery**

```
 $( ".ExpiryDate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", minDate: '0' ,changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,yearRange: "2015:2060"});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="propertiesAllDiv" style="height: 10px;  display: inline-block;"> <h2 style="float:left; margin: 0px;">Expiry Date</h2><font style="color:red;">*</font></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Datepicker: changeYear + yearRange causes flash in Firefox**](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5493)

> This issue in Firefox 3.6 and JQuery UI 1.8.14 Firefox does not handle well scrolling in a hidden dropdown. I think this can be solved by not selecting the year in the dropdown if the datepicker is not showing. The year can be initially selected after the picker shows on _showDatePicker instead.

Comment: Here Datepicker is showing but not dropdown is not working..@Naveen